# Test if array of the form [x_1, x_2, x_3 ...]

Tags: php, arrays

I got a PHP object which can be an array or not.

I'd like to check not only that it's an array (which can be indexed by strings) but that it's an array of the form `[x_1, x_2, x_3 ...]`.

Therefore the function `is_array` doesn't suit me.

But what instead?

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far

Comment: There are several ways to do it. I'm looking for the most concise/professional.

Comment: Show at least one way that you've tried.

Comment: Yes it does RickN. So I guess that PHP has no built-in function for this.